# Adobe After Effect CS5 10.0 to 10.5 Updater not working?

Tags: windows, software-update, adobe-after-effects

I have installed my Adobe After Effect CS5 version 10.0.0.458,
and i'm planning to upgrade to the CS5 version 10.5 (Found from [this adobe link)](https://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/product.jsp?product=13&platform=Windows).

But strangely, from the 2 links given on that page.

1. Adobe After Effects CS5.5 10.5.1 Update for Retail DVD
2. Adobe After Effects CS5.5 10.5.1 Update for Electronic Download

Both installer seems not working for me. It just gave me message :

**"Some updates failed to install. Update is not applicable.**"

Any clue how to solve this? I prefer not to download the Big Installer (DVD).

Comment: Have you tried again? A thing like this often happens due to incomplete downloads. If retrying doesn't help, then the definitions of AE could have possibly been corrupted. Try re-installing AE CS5 10.0.0.458 and then try updating.

Comment: i downloaded two of the files completely without any interruptions (nor paused / stopped). The update installer seems not matching or something? @ProgyadeepMoulik

Comment: Maybe you can try downloading Adobe CS 10.5 directly? (torrents)